# I tried validating my css file but cant find the issue for resizing to tablet size for grid layout

Tags: html, css

Sorry im new to HTML/CSS. I have a CSS file that I believe to be working everything works except I cant figure out why my resizing from large screen to medium screen to small screen doesnt work. It jumps from 3 boxes in a row to 3 boxes in a column. Im trying to make the medium screen resize to 2 smaller boxes on top with 1 larger box on bottom. Sorry if this is a bad question. I will post my css file I dont believe its the HTML file. Thank you for helping

```css
      * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -26px;
  left: 21px;
  width: 150px;
}

section {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  clear: right;
}

#Chicken {
  background-color: salmon;
}

#Beef {
  background-color: red;
}

#Sushi {
  background-color: green;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-md-1,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-md-12 {
      float: left;
    }
    .col-md-1 {
      width: 8.33%
    }
    .col-md-2 {
      width: 16.66%
    }
    .col-md-3 {
      width: 25%
    }
    .col-md-4 {
      width: 33.33%
    }
    .col-md-5 {
      width: 41.66%
    }
    .col-md-6 {
      width: 50%
    }
    .col-md-7 {
      width: 58.33%
    }
    .col-md-8 {
      width: 66.66%
    }
    .col-md-9 {
      width: 74.99%
    }
    .col-md-10 {
      width: 83.33%
    }
    .col-md-11 {
      width: 91.66%
    }
    .col-md-12 {
      width: 100%
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .col-sm-1,
      .col-sm-2,
      .col-sm-3,
      .col-sm-4,
      .col-sm-5,
      .col-sm-6,
      .col-sm-7,
      .col-sm-8,
      .col-sm-9,
      .col-sm-10,
      .col-sm-11,
      .col-sm-12 {
        float: left;
      }
      .col-sm-1 {
        width: 8.33%
      }
      .col-sm-2 {
        width: 16.66%
      }
      .col-sm-3 {
        width: 25%
      }
      .col-sm-4 {
        width: 33.33%
      }
      .col-sm-5 {
        width: 41.66%
      }
      .col-sm-6 {
        width: 50%
      }
      .col-sm-7 {
        width: 58.33%
      }
      .col-sm-8 {
        width: 66.66%
      }
      .col-sm-9 {
        width: 74.99%
      }
      .col-sm-10 {
        width: 83.33%
      }
      .col-sm-11 {
        width: 91.66%
      }
      .col-sm-12 {
        width: 100%
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>module2-solution css</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our Menu</h1>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <section>
      <h2 id="Chicken">Chicken</h2>
      <p>Heat the olive oil in a small, non-stick pan over medium heat. Crack the egg directly into the pan and season generously with salt and pepper. Cook for about two minutes, then use a spatula to flip the egg, being careful not to break the yolk. For
        a runny yolk, turn off the heat and let the egg sit for one minute.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <section>
      <h2 id="Beef">Beef</h2>
      <p>Heat the olive oil in a small, non-stick pan over medium heat. Crack the egg directly into the pan and season generously with salt and pepper. Cook for about two minutes, then use a spatula to flip the egg, being careful not to break the yolk. For
        a runny yolk, turn off the heat and let the egg sit for one minute.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <section>
      <h2 id="Sushi">Sushi</h2>
      <p>Heat the olive oil in a small, non-stick pan over medium heat. Crack the egg directly into the pan and season generously with salt and pepper. Cook for about two minutes, then use a spatula to flip the egg, being careful not to break the yolk. For
        a runny yolk, turn off the heat and let the egg sit for one minute.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, we miss some part of your code, could you supply the rest of the relevant HTML code? Otherwise we cannot see what goes wrong.

Comment: I can but where do I add the html

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you used something called flexbox. I've used it before but don't remember anything except that it was great. If I were you I would look up the syntax for it. (; -A person on the internet

Comment: Hi and welcome! This is not an answer - consider edit it with code to demonstrate how `flexbox` can help here.

Comment: I would but in class the teacher said to not use any frameworks. Ive been trying to figure this out for like 4 hours now all I need id this one thing fixed and ill be done

Comment: Hi, flexbox is not a framework it is a CSS layout module, which can help you what you want to achieve, you could take a look and try some things out. On this website is a good guide on how it works: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ (also a good source for other HTML, CSS and JS knowledge) :)